# Linux AWK - custom filename while split a file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

`awk '/{start}/{filename=NR".split"}; {print > filename}' alltickets.txt`

This command split the file alltickets.txt in several files each time that find `{start}`.

right now the files produced are NR(number of the row).split.

`1.split
5.split
6.split`

I have a variable, let's say `VAR='xxx'`
And I want that this variable is contained in the file name

to obtain:

`1.xxx.split
2.xxx.split
3.xxx.split`

After that if possible i would like to write these files in a specific directory.

Can you help me?

I've tried several options but every time I got an error.

You can propose also other solutions than awk.

Comment: The `VAR='xxx'` is a shell variable? you want to pass that to `Awk`? Clearly state where the variable comes from

Comment: Why not just put the value in the command, like this : `awk '/{start}/{filename=NR".xxx.split"}; {print > filename}' alltickets.txt`, then copy the generated ones wherever you want.

Comment: This command is used in a script. The variable is not an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following once and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -v var="value_of_variable" '/{start}/{filename=NR "." var ".split";}; {print > filename}'   Input_file
```

Use `-v var="$shell_variable"` in case your variable has shell variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v dir='/path/to/files' -v var="$VAR" '
    /{start}/{close(filename); filename=dir "/" NR "." var ".split"}
    {print > filename}
' alltickets.txt`
```